# Android: Set material design elevation for button using AppCompat V7

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-elevation

When following [this Android tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html) using AppCompat V7 to get the new Tool Bar work, the `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` supports `android:elevation` on SDK's < Lollipop. This is because they use `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` and not `Toolbar`.

Is there equivalent for button? Something like `android.support.v7.widget.Button`? (This one not exist) Or any other workaround in the kind of overlaying the Button in some view supporting elevation? (I don't want implementation of creating custom shapes with gradients for look & feel of elevation).

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Floating Action Button from support design library .

Use below code to the layout where you want this button.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_fab"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                app:backgroundTint="#0091b4"
                app:elevation="6dp"
                app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

Do add design dependency in your project 
Add below in the dependency list of build.gradle file

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you will have to do what you do not want. Because there is no support button view yet. (As i know :) perhaps some omniscient person will correct my answer)

Comment: Button gets inflated to AppCompatButton by AppCompat's LayoutInflater however it doesn't backport elevation, just tinting.